# shQuote() breaks system() command rather than escaping spaces

Tags: r, escaping

I'm running the GCMS software AMDIS inside an R script to analyze GCMS data. The basic syntax is:

```
system("AMDIS_PATH GCMS_FILE_PATH /S /GC /GE /E"
```

With "/S /GC /GE /E" referring to functionalities within the AMDIS program.

I want to make the code 'fool-proof', so I'm allowing paths with "/" instead of "\\". And I'm also allowing spaces in the paths, escaping them with `shQuote(..., type = "cmd")`

Which means the full code looks like

```
system(paste(shQuote(gsub("/", "\\", AMDIS_PATH, fixed = T), type = 'cmd'), shQuote(gsub("/", "\\", GCMS_FILE_PATH, fixed = T), type = 'cmd'), "/S /GD /GS /E"))
```

This code does not work (output = 65535), but there's a catch:

If I remove the shQuotes from my GCMS_FILE_PATH. Then everything works like it should (so long as the FILE_PATH does not contain any spaces).
So executing the code like this does work:

```
system(paste(shQuote(gsub("/", "\\", AMDIS_PATH, fixed = T), type = 'cmd'), gsub("/", "\\", GCMS_FILE_PATH, fixed = T), "/S /GD /GS /E"))
```

Any idea why shQuote works fine for the AMDIS_PATH, but not for the GCMS_FILE_PATH? And how I can run my code and still escape spaces in the GCMS_FILE_PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Without [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's hard to say what is going on here, but note that `?system` says:

> On Windows, system does not use a shell and there is a separate function shell which passes command lines to a shell.

So escaping with `type = 'cmd'` *might* not be appropriate at all, consider using `system2` instead.

Your issue might either be with what you expect `system` to do or what you expect `shQuote` to do. You can easily disentangle the the two by replacing `system` with `cat` for debugging.